# Advanced Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

What is the best way to do advanced animations? I know there is frame animation (having a bunch of images and displaying them to look as they are being animated) 
I have run into a problem with this. I have had some very high resolution images, and quite a few number of images and the iPhone doesnt seem to keep up with the animation.(it jerks as if its skipping a frame now and then)
What is the best tool to use to have a super complex animation, a video like animation?
I have looked around and cannot find an answer, maybe im just not typing in the correct terms. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need to animate 'very high resolution' images?

Comment: For a childs story book, or a game. You know, like at the beginning of a game, there is a big animation/video that the user watches. I dont want it to play like a video, meaning i dont want there to be a nav bar allowing the user to fast forwards, rewind. I just want it to play. @TylerM

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1489

Comment: make a video, play it without the ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try animating from an array

```
yourImageView.animationImages=arrayOfImages;
yourImageView.animationDuration=5.0;
yourImageView.animationRepeatCount=1;

[yourImageView startAnimating];
```

and then set the delay to 5

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

Comment: this is using a number of images, which is what i dont want to do, for performance reasons. But thanks for the help!